# Expand (key: list) into a dictionary with all pairs of mappings

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Cant find another post with my exact problem and I'm struggling figuring it out.

```
for value in options:
    industry = value.get_attribute('value')
    if ":" in industry:
        param, industry = industry.split(":",1)
        industry = industry.strip()
        data[industry] = states
```

Outputs:

```
'GENERAL_IND_MISC': ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming']
```

Desired Output:

```
'GENERAL_IND_MISC': 'Alabama', 'GENERAL_IND_MISC': 'Alaska', 'GENERAL_IND_MISC': 'Arizona', 'GENERAL_IND_MISC': 'Arkansas' etc...
```

Basically putting the state as the value and copying the key for every state instead putting the list, I tried to use a for loop but it only iterated for one state.

Comment: A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: By design, dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

As written in comments, dictionary keys are unique (if they were not, they wouldn't be keys at all). I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but the closest thing you can create is a list:

```
>>> d = {'GENERAL_IND_MISC': ['Alabama', 'Alaska']}
>>> [(k, v) for k, vs in d.items() for v in vs]
[('GENERAL_IND_MISC', 'Alabama'), ('GENERAL_IND_MISC', 'Alaska')]
```

The list comprehension takes every pair `k, vs` where `vs` is a list of values and then pairs the key `k` with every value in `vs`.